# Trouble disabling/enabling multiple submit buttons on same form

Tags: jquery, forms, disabled-input

I have built a multi-step form in which there are submit buttons for each step. The first 2 submit buttons simply display the next part of the form and the last one posts the data.

I want to disable each submit button until the input fields are filled out, however, it is not working. Here's what I have:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <input id="Email" type="email"  value="" >          
    <input id="Password" type="password" />
    <input id="confirmPass" type="password" />
    <input id="emailPassSubmit" type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" disabled="disabled" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
 $('#Email, #Password, #confirmPass').onkeyup(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
           $('#emailPassSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
           $('#emailPassSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
      }
 });
});
</script>
```

This is the first page of the form and repeats the same in the other 2 steps. As of now, it disables the button but does not enable it.

Comment: Use keyup() instead onkeyup() and check the value you get but you can simplify your script with $('#emailPassSubmit').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == '');
I think you should use the change() event

Comment: you want to disable till all fields are filled?

Comment: IS this what u want? http://fiddle.jshell.net/yyH9A/

Comment: Thanks for your responses, it was the issue with onkeyup().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
$('#Email, #Password, #confirmPass').keyup(function(){

}
```

Because there is no such method onkeyup in jquery only keyup is available.

Dont forget to accept if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Give Id to your form and then submit it using jquery post via 
`$("#FormID").submit()`
and done validation using jquery validate, i hope this will work for you.